# How do I assign multiple values from the same key to a variable in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have to assign multiple values to variables from a dictionary. Here is a simplified snippet of my json.

```
'periods':[
    {'number': 1,
    'forecast': 'Sunny',
     },
    {'number': 2,
    'forecast': 'Light Rain, 20% chance'
    }]
```

I need to assign each value for forecast to a different variable.

Comment: Instead make a list or dictionary of `forecast` values

Comment: you can't have duplicate `keys`. dictionaries do not support that.

Comment: I can show you the full code if you want

Comment: bigbounty, how would i do that?

Comment: You can show some uses of this. For example, what is the expected way to assign values to `forecast`, and the way to get the values of it as well?

Comment: You would call it (the key)